# Blackberry Browser isn't working on handhelds but it does in the simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I'm trying to launch the Blackberry browser from within my app and it works for the simulator, but it doesn't for the device.
This is the code:

```
public static void launchBrowser(String url) {  
     BrowserSession session = Browser.getDefaultSession();  
     session.displayPage(url);  
}
```

It launched the browser, but it doesn't load the page. This is the error I get:

```
The protocol specified is not supported by the handheld.  
Please try a different url.
```

Is there a way to do this? I'm pretty much desperate :-S
Also, as I'm launching the stand alone browser, it should work with BIS too, right?
Thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: Problem fixed! Had forgotten to add the http:// before the url.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer to this question and then accept it.  That helps make it obvious that this question has been answered.

Comment: You're right. Just posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed! Had forgotten to add the http:// before the url